# Connecting to Interactive Broker Server using IB Python API & IB Gateway client on Linux

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am trying to connect to Interactive Broker(IB) server using their IB Python API & IB Gateway client. I am trying to do it on Linux box. I have downloaded & installed the API package & client from their websites on the linux box. I am also able to import IBapi library but am not able to connect to server. Getting the following error :

```
ERROR -1 502 Couldn't connect to TWS. Confirm that "Enable ActiveX and Socket EClients" 
is enabled and connection port is the same as "Socket Port" on the 
TWS "Edit->Global Configuration...->API->Settings" menu. Live Trading ports: 
TWS: 7496; IB Gateway: 4001. Simulated Trading ports for new installations 
of version 954.1 or newer:  TWS: 7497; IB Gateway: 4002
```

With this piece of code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
          def __init__(self):
              EClient.__init__(self, self)
app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 4002, 7211)
```

I am just getting started with IB api and am not sure whats the issue ? Is there a restriction on where to download & install IB Gateway client ?

Please help. Thank you !

Comment: What happens if you try setting the second argument of `app.connect` to 4001? Will that connect?

Comment: Nah ! Already tried it.

Comment: Hmm. Are you running your app on the same system running IB Gateway?

Comment: I think that might be the issue. I have IB python api on  linux box. I did try to install IB gateway on linux as well, but I am not sure if it happened correctly. If you could point me to something to correctly install IB gateway on linux & using it in python code , that would be really helpful. (I have followed IB documentation on installing IB gateway on linux. Its not very helpful frankly).

Comment: Rather than 127.0.0.1, put your virtual server IP in connect method. also, uncheck "allow connection from localhost only" in settings and add your system (client) IP to the list

Comment: and open the port in firwall

Answer (score 2):

By default, remote access to the API is disabled. To change this, open the Configure > Settings menu in IB Gateway and expand the API > Settings entry on the left. Toward the bottom, you should find options that allow remote access.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently not available for commission free accounts anymore (as of Jan 5, 2022). Both TWS (API option greyed out) and the Gateway (throwing an error when launching).